# Wix: Issue while opening installer

Tags: wix, wix3.5, windows-installer

Posting this again as my previous question I think has expired.

Sometimes my wix installer gives an error that looks something like:

This installation package could not be opened. Verify that this is a valid Windows package.

What does this mean? Looks like this is an error thrown by the msiexec program to indicate a corrupted install package or software.

Is there something we can do from a code/wix perspective to handle this?...even though this seems to be more of a file corruption issue.

This is what I see when I run verbose logging while installing.

I checked the md5 hash for both the installer on the machine and others, they do match.

```
=== Verbose logging started: 10/16/2013  6:36:20  Build type: SHIP UNICODE 5.00.7601.00  Calling process: C:\Windows\system32\msiexec.exe ===
MSI (c) (3C:D8) [06:36:20:134]: Font created.  Charset: Req=0, Ret=0, Font: Req=MS Shell Dlg, Ret=MS Shell Dlg

MSI (c) (3C:D8) [06:36:20:134]: Font created.  Charset: Req=0, Ret=0, Font: Req=MS Shell Dlg, Ret=MS Shell Dlg

MSI (c) (3C:24) [06:36:20:134]: Resetting cached policy values
MSI (c) (3C:24) [06:36:20:134]: Machine policy value 'Debug' is 0
MSI (c) (3C:24) [06:36:20:134]: ******* RunEngine:
           ******* Product: MyServer.msi
           ******* Action: 
           ******* CommandLine: **********
MSI (c) (3C:24) [06:36:20:134]: Incrementing counter to disable shutdown. Counter after increment: 0
MSI (c) (3C:24) [06:36:20:150]: Machine policy value 'DisableUserInstalls' is 0
MSI (c) (3C:24) [06:36:20:150]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer 3: 2 
MSI (c) (3C:24) [06:36:20:150]: Decrementing counter to disable shutdown. If counter >= 0, shutdown will be denied.  Counter after decrement: -1
MSI (c) (3C:24) [06:36:20:150]: MainEngineThread is returning 2
=== Verbose logging stopped: 10/16/2013  6:36:20 ===
```

Comment: Sadly the log doesn't say anything at all (always look for "value 3" when reading wix installer logs). Are you compiling it for the correct CPU architecture?

Comment: You haven't written, if this setup is working fine at other PCs. If yes, it is _very_ more likely that there is a single configuration problem on that PC.  Other MSI files (I use for example Orca for a quick test) do install well? Is it a user specific install or machine install with admin rights already elevated when you start? There is a log line referencing the policy settings in HKCU. Have you checked this?